# Unknown provider: AuthenticationServiceProvider <- AuthenticationService <- loginControl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to create an authentication service, and tried to call this in my controller, but I got some error like this

```
!JavaScript ERROR: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthenticationServiceProvider <- AuthenticationService <- loginControl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthenticationServiceProvider%20%3C-%20AuthenticationService%20%3C-%20loginControl
http://localhost:53512/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12696
```

I created service using `.factory`, my service like bellow

```
'use strict';
angular.module('pocket.login', ['ionic'])
.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        //My Code Here
    }])
```

and I have a controller like this

```
'use strict';
angular.module('pocket.login', ['ionic'])
.controller('loginControl', function($rootScope,$scope,$http,$state,$ionicLoading,$cookieStore,AuthenticationService) {
    //Just an example of calling service
    AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
});
```

And i have the app.js too, and I rdy declared the Controller and Service at app.js but it still not work

```
'use strict';
angular.module('pocket.login', []);
angular.module('pocket', ['ionic',
    'ngCordova', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngIdle', 'ngCookies',
    'pocket.welcome', 'pocket.registration',
    'pocket.login', 'pocket.navigation', 'pocket.account',
    'pocket.about'
])
```

I don't know how to inject my service correctly, I hope you want to help me to solve this problem.

**Regard,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

READY SOLVED THIS PROBLEM.

In factory

```
'use strict';
angular.module('pocket') //it should be change to root Module not login module.
.factory('AuthenticationService',
    ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        //My Code Here
    }])
```